# How do you print an object, called * (asterisk)?

Tags: php, object, stdclass

If `print_r($object)` returns

```
stdClass Object
(
    [*] => sometext
)
```

How do I get the property of the asterisk, i.e `$object->*`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can access the property like this

```
$object->{"*"}
```

Comment: @timofey read more here [Complex (curly) syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex)

Comment: Thanks for the link! Great info.

Answer (score 2):

Does this work;

```
  print_r($object->{'*'});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just

```
print_r($object->{"*"});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also convert your object to an array :

```
$array = get_object_vars($object);
echo $array['*'];
```

But answers above are even better :

```
$object->{"*"}
```